# Подписка PayPal (регулярные платежи), период действия

Tags: php, html, paypal

1. Создание регулярного платежа. Регулярный платеж задается следующими параметрами:

   ```
   $params['cmd'] = '_xclick-subscriptions';
   $params['a3'] = 123;
   $params['p3'] = '1';
   $params['t3'] = 'M';
   $params['src'] = '1';
   ```

   Подробнее тут: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/
2. По настроенному `notify_url` будут отправляться уведомления об изменении подписки такие как "создание подписки", окончание подписки", "статус оплаты".
3. У каждой подписки есть свой `subscr_id`. Он приходит в этих уведомлениях.

Вопрос: можно ли как то получить дату следующего списания?

Например у нас первый платеж был 29 февраля. Какую дату через 1 месяц установит PayPal - неявно. По этому просто прибавить месяц не получиться. В личном кабинете PayPal у каждого регулярного платежа есть эта дата. Именно ее нужно получить через API PayPal, чтобы вывести на своем сайте.